# Looking for new hosting after Dreamhost

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for new personal hosting after using Dreamhost for a while. I'm looking for hosting which has the following features:

```
* Shell access (obviously)
* Prebuilt LAMP stack (optional)
* Python/Ruby support
* Scalable
* Good speeds around the world (I travel a lot)
* Not too expensive?
```

What are you using currently for hosting and why do you like it?

Comment: Ah, Ruby support is the biggest drawback with DreamHost's shared hosting. Is that the reason you're leaving DreamHost? Also, you should just edit your other web hosting question as they're really 2 parts of the same question.

Comment: "0 down vote favorite Share on Facebook Share on Twitter" - copied from somewhere else I take it?

Answer (score 1):

### HostMonster

they have worked great for me over the last few years,  great support and all the features you need.

Lunarpages is another host I use that works great and I believe they have all those features.

Answer (score 0):

Site5 is decent and cheap - they went through a period in the past where they screwed some stuff up and their support wasn't great, but they've been good since a year or two ago.

Answer (score 0):

I like Media Temple. It's more expensive then dreamhost, however, the price determines the quality. The customer service is so much better.

http://mediatemple.net/